# pcolormesh adds empty white columns

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to do a simple heatmap with *pcolormesh* and I run into this weird effect with some sizes, which add empty white columns. If I create a 10x30, as below, it works perfectly.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

d = []
for x in range(10):
    d.append([])
    for y in range(30):
        d[-1].append(y)

plt.pcolormesh(np.array(d))
plt.show()
```

But, if I try with a 10x37:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

d = []
for x in range(10):
    d.append([])
    for y in range(34):
        d[-1].append(y)

plt.pcolormesh(np.array(d))
plt.show()
```

I got those weird white columns at the end. This seems to hold for a couple of values (10x11 fails, but 10x12 works... I wasn't able to discerna  pattern.
[image: Result of 10x37]

Is there any way to remove them, maybe forcing the final size of the heatmap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of axes limits and aspect ratio, `pcolormesh` acts less like an image, and more like a line plot. If you want to show the elements of an array as pixels, you can use `imshow`. Alternatively, you can set the x-limits of your `pcolormesh` plot. Consider the following example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

d1 = []
d2 = []
for x in range(10):
    d1.append([])
    d2.append([])
    for y in range(30):
        d1[-1].append(y+x)

    for y in range(37):
        d2[-1].append(y+x)



fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(10,4))

# your first two examples
axes[0].pcolormesh(np.array(d1), cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
axes[1].pcolormesh(np.array(d2), cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)

# let's reset the x-lims on this
axes[2].pcolormesh(np.array(d2), cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
axes[2].set_ylim(bottom=0, top=d2.shape[0])
axes[2].set_xlim(left=0, right=d2.shape[1])
# or more concisely (thanks Joe): 
axes[2].axis('tight')

# and use imshow here
axes[3].imshow(np.array(d2), cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
```

and that gives us:

[image]

Comment: Great thanks, the problem with imshow (that I was using previously), is that you can't save the figures as a nice vector graphic. The colors in the map are always really blurry.

Comment: @Zenon hmm. I've never had that problem. are you setting the dpi sufficiently high with your call to `savefig`? you can also mess with its interpolation options.

Comment: I tried, but by setting it large enough (like 800), the file size becomes just ridiculous for large graphics (10k x 10k lines). Thus the option of vector images provided by *pcolormesh* seems perfect.

Comment: @Zenon understood. I recommend setting the axes limits (and aspect) explicitly in that case. I'll modify the example to show how to do this more elegantly.

Comment: @PaulH - Alternately you could call `ax.axis('tight')` to automatically set the axes limits to the bounds of the data, rather than manually specifying them.